# No exported member HttpClientModule, BrowserAnimationsModule

Tags: angular

I just updated angular to version 5.1.2. Now I'm getting this error from my imports of the modules mentioned in the title:

```
Module '"c:/pdws-view-v2/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations"' has 
no exported member 'BrowserAnimationsModule'.
```

My application seems to be working just fine though, for example the http calls are successful. I am wondering what the problem is (if there even is one).

Here are the imports:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Thanks.

Comment: Restart your editor, probably needs to refresh it's module import indexes

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments above, restart your editor.

Just upgraded Angular 7 -> 8 and experienced many similar errors coming out of multiple `@Angular` imports. App still built and ran even with these issues though.